# Add items to list of type in vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

How do I add the values to the items in the list. The list type is this class:-

```
<SoapType("TOBWeeksHeld", "urn:daeoverbrandIntf")> _
Public Class TOBWeeksHeld
    Public siteID As String
    Public checkIn As String
    Public resortName As String
    Public country As String
    Public region As String
    Public locality As String
    Public weekId As String
    Public bedrooms As String
    Public sleeps As String
    Public bookingType As String
    Public resortId As String
    Public timeToExpiry As String
    Public specialFlag As String
    Public extMemberNo As String
End Class
```

Everything I try, such as:-

```
Dim newWeeksOnHold As New List(Of TOBWeeksHeld)
With newWeeksOnHold(0)
.siteID = siteID
.checkIn = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).checkIn()
.resortName = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).resortName()
.country = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).country()
.region = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).region()
.locality = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).locality()
.weekId = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).weekId()
.bedrooms = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).bedrooms()
.sleeps = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).sleeps()
.bookingType = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).bookingType()
.resortId = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).resortId()
.timeToExpiry = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).timeToExpiry()
.specialFlag = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).specialFlag()
.extMemberNo = weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld(i).extMemberNo()
End With
```

Gives me the same error in the debugger that index is out of range on the "With newWeeksOnHold(0)" line. I'm guessing it's because the list is empty and I'm telling it to go to a particular Index. However, I've tried Add, and Insert and a few other things to no avail.

The purpose of this is to read in a web service result and output it as a different class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not inserted anything in the list, so the list is empty.

```
Dim newWeeksOnHold As New List(Of TOBWeeksHeld)
newWeeksOnHold.Add(New TOBWeeksHeld) ' <-- insert a new item
With newWeeksOnHold(0)
'...
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry to your list before setting elements on it. newWeeksOnHold is still empty